# setState not redrawing widget tree when updating StatefulWidget Property

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building a simple list app where a user can add items to the list. Here is the full code.

```dart
class ItemsListView extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Item> items;
  const ItemsListView({super.key, required this.items});
  static const routeName = '/';

  @override
  State<ItemsListView> createState() {
    return _ItemsListViewState();
  }

}

class _ItemsListViewState extends State<ItemsListView> {

  void _addItem() async {
    final newItem = await Navigator.of(context).push<Item>(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => CreateItemView(),
      ),
    );

    if (newItem != null) {
      setState(() {
        widget.items.add(newItem);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        drawer: Drawer(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Items'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: _addItem,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: widget.items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Row(
              children: [Text(widget.items[index].label)],
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

An `Item` is a class I defined myself to model an item. It only has two properties: `String id` and `String label`.

The list is prepopulated with hard-coded dummy data via the `ItemsListView` constructor.

```dart
final List<Item> items;
const ItemsListView({super.key, required this.items});
```

A user can add a new item using a separate screen. This screen is a simple form which takes a string as the input for the `label` property. The `id` property is generated.

Once submitted, the screen returns an `Item` object, and from there, I simply add the new item to the list. This is all in the `_addItem` method.

```dart
  void _addItem() async {
    final newItem = await Navigator.of(context).push<Item>(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => CreateItemView(),
      ),
    );

    if (newItem != null) {
      setState(() {
        widget.items.add(newItem);
      });
    }
  }
```

I put some print statements around the `setState` call to check the `widget.items` list and I can see that the new item is being added. However, the screen is not displaying the new item.

Any ideas?

Comment: It does for me, maybe try running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`?

Answer (score 1):

You should put the `items` state inside the `State` (which is `_ItemsListViewState`, in this case), and not in the widget (`ItemsListView`).

From the [`setState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) documentation:

> Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for this State object.

So you should have done it like this:

```dart
class _ItemsListViewState extends State<ItemsListView> {
  late List<Item> items;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    // ...
    items = widget.items; // Initialize the state with data from the widget
  }
}
```

Modify the state like this:

```
setState(() {
  items.add(newItem);
});
```

And use `items` like this:

```dart
body: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: items.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Row(
      children: [Text(items[index].label)],
    );
  },
));
```